# puppeteer fingerprint - I am unable to override webGL vendor and render

Tags: webrtc, webgl, puppeteer, fingerprint

I am writing an puupeteer project for scraping web site.
I use stealth plugin for puppeteer because website detect me as a bot.

And everything was going well until I decided to check my browser on iphey.com

It shows me that I am trying to spoof my hardware
https://prnt.sc/1qk7t01

In details of hardware section I cannot get some useful info except to https://prnt.sc/1qk7wu3

As I understand it is hashs or something like this.

I decided to go further and check my puppeteer instance on https://browserleaks.com/

all the sections of the site are next

ip - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1__U5UK0D2xZVttXPhzUKzn06iUhUR9Jy/view?usp=sharing

rest in the comments bellow

And if I trully understand main problem with my puppeteer is WebGL Vendor and Rernder.
I would like to override them but have no idea how to do that.

Can you help me to ecome undetectable for iphey.com with my instance of puppeteer.

github - https://github.com/Golofaevap/myBrowser

I hope you will help me to find some solution

Comment: javascript - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlzuMGQKp4tpkPMkP_M4jVyaNEEvEkYL/view?usp=sharing
webrtc - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WnT10hOc3BKSDozYNNJtWgHqTyf9b1OA/view?usp=sharing
webgl - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlzuMGQKp4tpkPMkP_M4jVyaNEEvEkYL/view?usp=sharing
geolocation - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_yhnhJ-z9dsbQVMlqUI8HBYnfaCRIw7t/view?usp=sharing
canvas - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NP6aqKhRAp7feXZoBBfRwAoJX9JHnhOk/view?usp=sharing
font - https://drive.google.com/file/d/17nP1c60kTZRF0PyORnJHhIPMrhUfWqwZ/view?usp=sharing